# Am I allowed to use "in" and "where" within a haskell definition?

Tags: haskell

I'm in the process of learning haskell, so I tried to make a the following function to see if I could do it.

This is what I wrote

```
projectileY :: (Num a, Fractional a) => a -> a -> a -> a -> a
projectileY gravity time vInit height = let equation gr ti veli hei = -0.5*g*(t^2)+vi*t+h
                                        in if (equation g t vi h < 0) then 0 else (equation g t vi h)
                                            where
                                                g = gravity
                                                t = time
                                                vi = vInit
                                                h = height

main :: IO()
main = do
  print (projectileY 9.8 0.1 2.0 100)
```

This was the error

```
parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

So I tried messing with the indentation for a while, with no success. Am I allowed to use "in" and "where" like this?

Comment: Your question is missing some important parts.

Comment: I don't need you to solve this, I just want to know if "in" and "where" can be used together like this. EDIT: I just realized what you're talking about. Stack overflow what being glitchy and removed my code blocks.

Comment: Just move the stuff from the `let` into the `where` and get rid of the `let`.

Comment: i can't help you with the indenting, but using gravity, g and gr in to represent that same thing in a function is going to get you into trouble I fear

Comment: As posted here, your code works (except for the unrelated issue of a missing `Ord` constraint). My guess is that you are mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: @Simon: The variable names were something I was messing with to see if that would help. I know its stupid, but I tried anyway. I wouldn't actually release code like this, don't worry.

Comment: @duplode, I thought Num contained Ord as well, does it not?

Comment: `> :i Num` shows it doesn't inherit from `Ord`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you change the type signature and do some cleaning up (proper indentation, not mixing tabs and spaces), it should work. This is an working code:

```
projectileY :: (Fractional a, Ord a) => a -> a -> a -> a -> a
projectileY gravity time vInit height = let equation gr ti veli hei = -0.5*g*(t^2)+vi*t+h
                                        in if (equation g t vi h < 0) 
                                           then 0 
                                           else (equation g t vi h)
                                               where
                                                 g = gravity
                                                 t = time
                                                 vi = vInit
                                                 h = height

main :: IO()
main = print (projectileY 9.8 0.1 2.0 100)
```

> Am I allowed to use "in" and "where" like this?

Yes. But note that `in` should be used alongside with `let`. The let in syntax should form an expression.

Comment: So basically, don't use tabs at all?

Comment: @Maz Not using them is the easiest way.

Comment: @Maz: Or, if you __really__ want to use them, make sure that `let` is on its own line and indented with tabs.

Comment: @Maz, I would never use them. GHC 7.10 produces a warning by default if your file has any tabs in it; in older versions you can use `-fwarn-tabs`. Using tabs really puts you at the mercy of your editor.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others wrote about indents, it hardly makes sense to define a local function and then to twice apply it with the same set of arguments. On the whole, you make it all too complicated for no gain.

Why not write simply?:

```
projectileY g t v0 h0 = max 0.0 (-0.5 * g * (t ^ 2) + v0 * t + h0)
```

As another style note, in physical formulae, I find it much more readable to use conventional short identifiers for variables and constants, such as `g`, `h` and `t`.

Comment: I was experimenting with "where" and "in." I know I forced them in. The strange names were just an experiment to check if using the same variable names screwed something up.